# How can I send a SMS (Instead of MMS) from a Motorola Atrix 4G?

Tags: sms, mms

I was writing a text when suddenly I noticed the message say MMS not SMS. How do I change it back?

Answer (score 1):

It automatically changes to MMS when a message's length goes over 160 bytes (160 ASCII characters). You should be able to go back to SMS by starting a new message.